# Sanitize Wordpress Metabox Fields (POST array) - The right way

Tags: php, wordpress, sanitization

I´m working on a wordpress plugin with Metaboxes. The plugin got rejected because of the Sanitize of metabox fields.

**My `save_fields` function**

```
public function save_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['modalsettings_nonce'] ) )
        return $post_id;
    $nonce = $_POST['modalsettings_nonce'];
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'modalsettings_data' ) )
        return $post_id;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
    foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
        $userInput = $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ];
        if ( isset( $userInput ) ) {
            switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                case 'email':
                    $userInput = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    $userInput = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                    break;
            }
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], $userInput );
        } else if ( $meta_field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], '0' );
        }
    }
}
```

**The comment from wordpress review team**

> ### Data Must be Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated
>
> When you include POST/GET/REQUEST/FILE calls in your plugin, it's
>   important to sanitize, validate, and escape them. The goal here is to
>   prevent a user from accidentally sending trash data through the
>   system, as well as protecting them from potential security issues.
>
> SANITIZE: Data that is input (either by a user or automatically) must
>   be sanitized as soon as possible. This lessens the possibility of XSS
>   vulnerabilities and MITM attacks where posted data is subverted.
>
> VALIDATE: All data should be validated, no matter what. Even when you
>   sanitize, remember that you don’t want someone putting in ‘dog’ when
>   the only valid values are numbers.
>
> ESCAPE: Data that is output must be escaped properly when it is
>   echo'd, so it can't hijack admin screens. There are many esc_*()
>   functions you can use to make sure you don't show people the wrong
>   data.
>
> To help you with this, WordPress comes with a number of sanitization
>   and escaping functions. You can read about those here:
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/
>
> Remember: You must use the most appropriate functions for the context.
>   If you’re sanitizing email, use sanitize_email(), if you’re outputting
>   HTML, use esc_html(), and so on.
>
> An easy mantra here is this:
>
> Sanitize early Escape Late Always Validate
>
> Clean everything, check everything, escape everything, and never trust
>   the users to always have input sane data. After all, users come from
>   all walks of life.
>
> Example(s) from your plugin:
>
> stylistic-modals/admin/metaboxes.php:202: $userInput = $_POST[
>   $meta_field['id'] ]; if ( isset( $userInput ) ) { switch (
>   $meta_field['type'] ) { case 'email': $userInput = sanitize_email(
>   $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] ); break; case 'text': $userInput =
>   sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] ); break; }
>   update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], $userInput );
>
> Because you save $userInput later down, you must sanitize it.

**What can I do?**

I have no more ideas what Wordpress want from me and when should I sanitize the fields...also if I search for examples I find just this way to sanitize $_POST arrays....

Do you have any idea?

### Edit: Will this work?

```
public function save_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['modalsettings_nonce'] ) )
        return $post_id;
    $nonce = $_POST['modalsettings_nonce'];
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'modalsettings_data' ) )
        return $post_id;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
    foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] ) ) {
            $sanitizedUserInput = "";
            $sanitizedMetaFieldID = "";
            switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                case 'email':
                    $sanitizedUserInput = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                    $sanitizedMetaFieldID = sanitize_email( $meta_field['id']);
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    $sanitizedUserInput = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                    $sanitizedMetaFieldID = sanitize_text_field( $meta_field['id']);
                    break;
                default:
                    $sanitizedUserInput = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                    $sanitizedMetaFieldID = sanitize_text_field( $meta_field['id']);
            }
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $sanitizedMetaFieldID, $sanitizedUserInput );
        } else if ( $meta_field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
            $sanitizedMetaFieldID = sanitize_text_field( $meta_field['id']);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $sanitizedMetaFieldID, '0' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have this assigning `$userInput = $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ];` there before the `if` statement. Then you've a `switch` statement. Now, say, on some reasons, the php execution flow doesn't access to `switch` statement.

Next up, the php execution flow reaches here:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], $userInput );
```

That means the `$userInput` variable is NOT being then sanitized. This may be the reason. I hope this would help you.

Comment: So.. would be be better to just add a default statement into the switch statement with the $userInput variable and remove the declaration before the if statement?

Comment: Well, you may declare a new variable inside `if` statement, `$sanitizedUserInput = ""` for example, then change others inside `switch` statement and eventually pass it to the `update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field[ 'id' ], $sanitizedUserInput )`.

Comment: Thanks! I´ve edited my main post. Will the new example work?

Comment: hmm this should work. But you may need to sanitize meta_key `$meta_field[ 'id' ]` in other case.

Comment: Yes! It seems foolproof to me.